# "Noise word" in indexing services

Tags: indexing-service, noise-words

Can anyone please tell me, what exactly noise word means in indexing services? I am working on windows server indexing services and getting lots of issues.                               `Some questions on it:                                                                       Does indexing services not search for noise words?                                                                                                                                                                          What is the location and name of noise word file on windows server?`                               Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same as stop-words:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop-words

> In computing, stop words are words which are filtered out prior to, or after, processing of natural language data (text). There is not one definite list of stop words which all tools use and such a filter is not always used. Some tools specifically avoid removing them to support phrase search.

See also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693206%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> Noise words act as placeholders in phrase queries. A document that contains the text "wag the dog" is stored in the index with "wag" at occurrence 1 and "dog" at occurrence 3. The phrase query "wag dog" does not match, but the phrase query "wag a dog" does, because the occurrence information matches

Comment: Where I will get this noise word file? I found it in C:\Windows\System32.

Comment: There are more than 1 file. noise.enu, noise.jpn, noise.data etc. So, which file indexing service is using?

Comment: And if I want to search for noise word also. So, what should I do? Whether I should remove noise word from "noise" files or do some thing different?